# Laptop keeps crashing and freezing (mce: Hardware Error)

Tags: laptop, cpu, freeze, thinkpad, intel

I bought a used ThinkPad L540 and it crashes and freezes all the time. After a reboot the GNOME Logs app reports the following errors:

```
kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1671640567 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 28
kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 
kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 2: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: f2003380000f0150
```

Most of the time the freezes occur when I'm running multiple and/ or intensive tasks but sometimes the laptop even freezes while I'm just watching YouTube Videos.

I read that this error can be caused by faulty ram, so I ran a MemTest86 and got no errors. I also replaced the thermal paste, because I read that overheating can be the reason for this error. It didn't help.

These are my specs:

Laptop model: Lenovo ThinkPad L540

CPU: Intel Core i7-4700MQ

RAM: 2x 4GB DDR3-1600

OS: Archcraft

Answer (score 0):

A reboot might be caused by heat, but a crash is somthing bigger, check the dirvers and update them.
This problem is more foucsed on the hardware side. No clear answer could be given without physical inspection. I suggest to send it to a trusted local speicalist.
--Good luck and give us updates for more further help to the community

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took the laptop to a local repair shop. The person running the shop said that the problem is probably caused by a faulty CPU. Thankfully the CPU of this model isn't soldered to the motherboard. So I baught a new CPU, changed it and now it works fine.